# Why are text objects altered when modifying SVG files with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, svg, beautifulsoup, inkscape

I'm using the BeautifulSoup module in python3 to modify some svg files I created with Inkscape. Specifically I'm modifying some of the text in these files and, in some cases, changing the colors of some objects. I've noticed, regardless of what I do, the position of all text is always shifted in the output svg files. **For example see:** [svg in/out files + png versions](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AiZbxet-1qKXolRVYICED3rxUQcJ)

What appears to be happening is the size of the text objects is different in the output svg compared to the original file. I can copy the text object from the output file to original file and I no longer see the shift, but this is an annoying solution.

**Does anyone know what is causing this change to the text object size and can it be prevented?**

Here's an example bit of code I have run (copies of the input and output svgs are at the link above):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

svgFile = "test_in.svg"
outputFile = "test_out.svg"

svg = open(svgFile, 'r').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(svg, features = 'xml')
texts = soup.findAll('text')

for t in texts:
    if t['id'] == 'testID':
        print(t, '\n')
        t.contents[0].string = 'new text'
        print(t, '\n')

# Output the edited SVG file
f = open(outputFile, "w")
f.write(soup.prettify())
f.close()
```

There doesn't appear to be any change to the text elements within the xml/svg tree, so I feel like the issue has to be from a change to some other part of the file. (Also, I can omit `t.contents[0].string = 'new text'` and the text movement still occurs.) The first `print(t)` gives:

```
<text id="testID" inkscape:label="#text3581" sodipodi:linespacing="125%" style="font-size:20px;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;line-height:125%;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:Arial;-inkscape-font-specification:Arial" transform="matrix(0,1,-1,0,0,0)" x="449.63721" xml:space="preserve" y="-280.92737"><tspan id="tspan3583" sodipodi:role="line" style="font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;-inkscape-font-specification:Arial" x="449.63721" y="-280.92737">Text to change</tspan></text>
```

The output of the second print(t) appears to be exactly the same, except `'text to change'` is now `'new text'`:

```
<text id="testID" inkscape:label="#text3581" sodipodi:linespacing="125%" style="font-size:20px;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;line-height:125%;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:Arial;-inkscape-font-specification:Arial" transform="matrix(0,1,-1,0,0,0)" x="449.63721" xml:space="preserve" y="-280.92737"><tspan id="tspan3583" sodipodi:role="line" style="font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;-inkscape-font-specification:Arial" x="449.63721" y="-280.92737">new text</tspan></text>
```

Any insights would be appreciated!

Comment: Please post a small svg sample of a text object that moves during your transformation.

Comment: Edited to include png versions of the input and output svg files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that you are adding extra spaces by inserting newlines and calling `prettify()`.

```
   <tspan id="tspan3583" sodipodi:role="line" style="font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;-inkscape-font-specification:Arial" x="449.63721" y="-280.92737">
    new text
   </tspan>
```

There are four extra spaces before the "new text".

Normally that wouldn't be a problem. By default in XML, spaces at the start of elements are stripped out.  Unfortunately your SVG file has the following attribute in your text element:

```
xml:space="preserve"
```

This tells the browser that you care about the spaces, and you want them to be preserved and displayed.

You have two solutions:

1. Stop adding newlines and/or prettifying
2. Check for, and remove any `xml:space` attributes from your target text elements.  Or change the value from `"preserve"` to `"default"`.

Comment: I know this was several months ago, but I finally got around to testing this. Solution 1 works great. All I had to do was replace `f.write(soup.prettify())` with `f.write(str(soup))`. Like you pointed out this stops the addition of newlines and leading spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. The problem is that when bs4 parses the file, it is adding the text content onto a new line, so there is extra whitespace being added before and after the text, which is why it is shifting inside the svg.

Here is a screenshot of your input svg file. You see the text is on the same line as the tags

[image]

On your output svg file (below) you will see the that after the bs4 parse, the 'new text' content is on a separate line from the tags. What has also happened is that there is now lots of white space before and after the text contet, which is what is causing its position to shift in the svg image. Am having this problem just now also, not sure what the solution is yet.

[image]

Comment: The gimmicky solution I came up with was to center my text before altering it with bs4. The white space still gets added, but the text doesn’t move. Now that I know the actual source of the problem I may try to spend some time trying to come up with a more elegant solution. Thanks for pointing this out.